# cordova playGamesServices Get user score from leaderboard

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, google-play-games, phaser-framework

I have used the below cordova plugin to connect to Google Play Games Services.
https://github.com/artberri/cordova-plugin-play-games-services

Every thing is working fine. But in the documentation its not mentioned, how to get the user score from leaderboard. 
I am using Phaser as my game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, you can find the various actions listed in the [`execute`](https://github.com/artberri/cordova-plugin-play-games-services/blob/master/src/com/berriart/cordova/plugins/PlayGamesServices.java#L119-L149) function.

It appears that there's an [`executeGetPlayerScore`](https://github.com/alejandro-lopez/cordova-plugin-play-games-services/blob/master/src/com/berriart/cordova/plugins/PlayGamesServices.java#L271-L313) function you can use.

The fork by [alejandro-lopez](https://github.com/alejandro-lopez/cordova-plugin-play-games-services) seems to have received recent updates, so it may be a fork you'd want to submit a pull request to to include this in the documentation, since issues are turned off.

From the asker, example code:

```
window.plugins.playGamesServices.getPlayerScore(
    {leaderboardId: 'someID'},
    function(data) {
        // do something with data.PlayerScore;
    },function(e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e)); 
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried calling getPlayerScore function. but its failing. still trying. +1 for showing me a way. I will accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Accepting your answer. Thank you. Please add this below code in your answer to help other people.

window.plugins.playGamesServices.getPlayerScore(
{leaderboardId: 'someID'}, function(data){
... // do somthing with data.PlayerScore;
},function(e){
alert(JSON.stringify(e));
});

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the example code; answer updated accordingly. I also updated my PR for the most recently updated fork of that plugin project to include a tweaked example from the above. https://github.com/alejandro-lopez/cordova-plugin-play-games-services/pull/1